# Waiting state when 4-5 queues are bind on a single rabbitmq Channel in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ Server 2.3.1 .

There are 5-6 queues in one channel.

The Queue consists of java beans.

And there are same number of scala actors which are cosuming a particular queue.
All these actors try to get queue message through common Queue manager which handle rabbitmq connection and channel.

there is only one connection and channel in this Queue manager.

Yesterday i do some changes in only one bean.

when i start consuming the messages it Gives me Exception  "local class incompatible".
I know this error should come but the fact is other actors goes into wating state even if there are messges in Other Queues.

Is it good practice to bind 4-5 queue to a single channel.
Or is this a bug when a exception occurs in a channel with 4-5 queue bindings when one Queue object gets cast Exception.

can anybody help me plz!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A channel is just a multithreaded connection to a RabbitMQ broker. All the queue consumers and message publishers would normally share a single channel. An incomprehensible message should not cause any problems on a channel.

What type of exchange are you using? What kind of routing key is on the messages that you publish to the exchange? What binding keys are you using when you bind your queues to the exchange?

Have you considered putting a version number into the message headers so that the message consumers know which version of java bean to expect? Then they would not need to raise exceptions in the normal course of work.